# How do I successfully make convincing sci-fi gun sounds

Tags: sound, sfx, scifi

I'm making sound effects for my game after being inspired by sci-fi games like Infinite Warfare.

I design my gun sounds by recording a drum thud and then I apply a slight distortion to it to make it sound "crispy". I then use my computer and audio editing software to overlay the sound with a copy of the thud but the second copy has more bass and is streched and echoed. I mix the 2 and then I create a single sine wave beep and add it to the mix. I then record the a metal stick striking a thin aluminum bar. I do this to add a metallic sound to the gun shot sound. Finally, I record an electrical hum and add it to the mix, after futher tweaking, I have a gun shot sound but it's not that convincing. What should I do to make it realistic?

You can see what I created so far at

zimrmusic.bandcamp.com

Comment: I like those sounds. You can also try phase rotation to just about anything to make it sound like this. Or just take a TB 303 and you have all the sounds of the future :P

Answer (score 1):

Your gun sounds have a strong mid range. Maybe use some multiband compression to bring out the lows a bit more, but more importantly...

ADD TRIGGER SOUNDS.

That little click can add so much. What I really feel like your sounds are missing is that bit of mechanical high-end. It can be quiet, but it'll take the sounds to another level.

Answer (score 1):

you are going in the right direction - experimentation is the key. Also try and experiment with sample rate conversion - record any material you use at a very high sample-rate i.e. 192kHz and then use pitch changing to bring out different qualities of the audio.